# Accessing the __unicode__ field of a ForeignKey in Django model

Tags: django, unicode, foreign-keys, admin

I've constructed a useful combined string in a model's __unicode__ to identify the individual record in Django.

I then have another model that refers to the first as a foreign key.

for my second model I want to construct the __unicode__ string for the second model using the __unicode__ string from the first model referenced by the ForeignKey.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    amount = models.DecimalField("invoice total", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    invoice_date = models.DateField("invoice date")
    def __unicode__(self):  # I want to reuse this string in class Charge
            return " ".join((
            unicode(self.supplier),
            self.invoice_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            u"£",
            unicode(self.amount)
        ))

class Charge(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    amount = models.DecimalField("amount charged to house", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField("item description", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return " ".join((
            self.invoice.__unicode__, #How do I do this?
            unicode(self.amount),
            self.description,
        ))
```

The **unicode** of the second model needs that of the first without constructing it again.

How do I refer to it? I thought I'd just put invoice in my __unicode__ and it would refer to the unicode string of index but of course it gets the whole instance of an Invoice.

Comment: Just do `self.invoice` the ` __unicode__` would be evaluated for you.

Comment: That's what I'd hoped but I got an error saying expected string or unicode, Invoice found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return u'%s %s %s' % (self.invoice, self.amount, self.description)
```

`unicode.__mod__()` sees the "%s" and calls `unicode()` on the element.

Comment: That does it - thanks. Out of interest if I wanted to explicitly call a function that had been "def'd" within the Class could I call it via the Foreign Key connection somehow?

Comment: @user3074252: Yes, the same way you always call methods.

Comment: I use django 1.6 and get: <foreign key> matching query does not exist. I have return '%s' % (self.<foreign key>,)